Square root of multiplication of PSD Matrices
If $A$ and $B$ are two PSD matrices, is the following statement correct?
$\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{AB}$
If they are orthogonalized in the same orthonormal basis, then this statement is correct, but I am not sure about the general case.

What is the meaning of the right hand side if $A$ and $B$ do not commute?

It means we multiply them first and then take the square root! @Lieven

What is the square root of a matrix that is not guaranteed to be symmetric?

So you mean the non-symmetric matrices do not have square root? @Lieven

Or at least, there is no unique definition of a square root. A PSD matrix has a unique PSD square root. For more general matrices, things get complicated.

I see, thanks! @Lieven

Your question does not make much sense, as square roots of a matrix are not unique in general. E.g. $\pmatrix{0&x\\ 0&0}$ is a square root of the zero matrix (which is positive semidefinite) for every number $x$.
So, the answer to your question really depends on the square roots chosen. Conventionally, when $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, $\sqrt{A}$ and $\sqrt{B}$ refers to their unique positive semidefinite square roots, but even if we accept this convention, the meaning of $\sqrt{AB}$ is still ambiguous, because $AB$ may not be positive semidefinite.
However, if $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular, we may take $\sqrt{AB}$ to mean the (unique) principal square root of $AB$. In the present context, since $A$ and $B$ are PSD and nonsingular, $AB$ has a positive spectrum. So, the principal square root of $AB$ is the unique square root with with a positive spectrum. For this square root, we may ask whether $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$ is equal to $\sqrt{AB}$.
Unfortunately, the answer is ‘no’. In fact, $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{AB}$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.
Suppose $\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}=\sqrt{AB}$. Then
$$
\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}
=(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B})^2
=(\sqrt{AB})^2
=AB
=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{B}.
$$
Therefore $\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$. In turn, $A$ and $B$ must commute.
Conversely, suppose that $AB=BA$. Then they can be simultaneously unitarily diagonalised as $UD_1U^\ast$ and $UD_2U^\ast$ respectively. Therefore $\sqrt{A}=U\sqrt{D_1}U^\ast$, $\sqrt{B}=U\sqrt{D_2}U^\ast$ and
$\sqrt{AB}=U\sqrt{D_1D_2}U^\ast=\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}$.
